# Resharper command to show file in explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-8.0

Is there any command/shortcut to show the *selected* file ( selected in  solution explorer) at the file system explorer ?

For example :

selecting a file : [image]

Pressing <kbd>something....</kbd>

And then this will show :

[image]

Comment: No, there is not. But it's should be easy to write/record macro that does what you want.

Comment: @Peri yes but at home i have also vs2012 ( at my home)  which doesnt support macro (IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it. no resharper is needed. nor  Productivity Power Tools

http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/Trackback.aspx?guid=f5dcc54e-dfbc-4f79-8bfa-0deeb31902d2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you install Productivity Power Tools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd this is for VS2012). There is an 'Open containing folder' command when you right click on a file.